# Access REST API with $resource service

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, rest

I am struggling to get the `$resource` service running as intended. I tried following the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) and this [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/) which seem to provide a fully working implementation. However using this I get stuck with 2 problems.

My (very basic) implementation:

the `$resource`-service:

```
app.factory('User', function ($resource) {
return $resource(
        'myurl/user/:id', 
        {id: '@_id'}, 
        {
            update: {method: 'PUT'}
        }
       );
});
```

how i call it in my controller:

```
$scope.user = User.get({id:$scope.myId});

//save a new user:
$scope.user.$save(function(){location.href = '#/mainpage';});

//delete a user
$scope.user.$delete({id:$scope.myId},function(){location.href = '#/mainpage';});

//update a user
$scope.user.$update({id: user.id}, function(){location.href = '#/mainpage';});
```

**My questions:**

1. **Edit: Solved thanks to Andre Kreienbring.** Why do i have to specify the id `{id:$scope.myId}` for the `$delete` service? according to the links above this should be done automatically. However if i skip this, the DELETE goes to `myurl/user` instead of `myurl/user/{myId}`.
2. The GET returns a promise, so that `$scope.user` contains the properties `$promise` and `resolved` in addition to the user-specific properties. If i send this to my REST API via PUT, the request gets denied because the backend can't parse the request body into a `User`-Object.

   > Unrecognized field "$promise", not marked as ignorable

To resolve this, i tried to extract the data when the promise gets fulfilled:

```
$scope.user = User.get({id:$scope.myId});
$scope.user.$promise.then(function(data){$scope.test = data});
```

The `$scope.test` in the above code still contains the properties `$promise` and `resolved`. How can i send a "clean" JSON-object to my REST API which does not include the `$promise`?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question:
According to the [documentation of $resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource):

> If the parameter value is prefixed with @ then the value for that
>   parameter will be extracted from the corresponding property on the
>   data object (provided when calling an action method)

So, when calling `$scope.user.$delete({id:$scope.myId}` `{id:$scope.myId}` is your data object.

Your paramDefaults option `{id: '@_id'}` makes $resource look up the data object for the value of 'id' => $scope.myId. Let's assume this value is '123'

The URL template parameter is then replaced by this value and becomes `myurl/user/123`

Comment: okay, this is a good explanation why the routing works when i include `{id:$scope.myId}` explicitly. But shouldn't the defaultParameters take care of this already when i instanciate the $resource service via `get({id: someID})` ? At least i got this impression from the examples - they claim that the call goes to url/{id} even if they do not specify an id explicitly for $delete!

Comment: Allright, this solved my first question: i was defaulting the id value with `{id: '@_id'}`. Because of the underscore, this could not be resolved to the `id`-variable of the corresponding data object. The routing works as expected when i define the default-parameters as {id: '@id'}!

Answer (score 0):

You want to make the methods on your user (do not uppercase) service explicit:

```
app.factory('user', function ($resource) {
    var User = $resource('myurl/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});

    return {
        get: get
    };

    function get(id){
        return User.get({ userId: id }).$promise;
    }
});
```

Use as:

```
user.get($scope.myId).then(function(user){
    $scope.user = user;
});
```

Comment: Why not using the service as Uppercase? In my apps I always using the first letter as uppercase and have no problems with that. You can better differentiate the service from a variable!

Comment: It's not common. In Angular we only uppercase the first character for controllers. See the styleguide from John Papa (https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide). For resources you do see the uppercasing though but not for the services.

Comment: uppercasing was done in the above linked example, the Angular documentation and the angular phonecat-Tutorial, so i assumed this was standard. However, i am trying your suggestion right now - thanks for the answer!

Comment: Using your code i get `TypeError: user.get(...) is undefined`

Comment: Ah, I didn't test it. I updated the thing so maybe that works for you

Comment: ok, this "works" and gives the same result as my code did before: the `$scope.user` contains some user-properties (name, adress, ...) plus `$promise` and `resolved`. Could you explain why this should provide a different result in theory than my previous approach via `$scope.user.$promise.then(function(data){$scope.test = data});` ?

Comment: It should not give you a different result. It's just a cleaner way of coding the thing and hopefully gives you some insight in how it works.

Comment: aren't you just wrapping the `$resource`-instance into another service which then still calls the built-in get-method from `$resource`? I either really don't understand what you are doing there, or this is just an additional layer before calling the method in my controller?!

Comment: okay, could you please explain why? (why is this cleaner and which advantages justify the additional code?) I would really appreciate some pointers here.

Comment: It makes the user service reusable, extendible, testable, maintainable, readable, etc. Basically it's just good practice.